# Conditional statement not working in react

Tags: reactjs

[link to error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKG70.png)The green check Icon should be displaying the green text 'Validated (T/F): TRUE' in green which is correct. However the red Icon should be showing expired(T/F): TRUE with a red color, however it is showing up as green. I am wanting to make a check to see whether or not the Icon is returning a green color

Here is my ternary:

```
  <b style={{color: getColor('action', props.request.is_valid ? 'green' : 'red'  )}}>Validated (T/F):
    {props.request.is_valid == null ? ' None' : props.request.is_valid ? ' TRUE' : ' FALSE'}
  </b>
```

Comment: What's `is_valid`? A boolean? A value or `null`? Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: it is a Boolean @DaveNewton

Comment: Then why are you checking for null?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your conditional 'props.request.is_valid ? 'green' : 'red''. That conditional (is_valid) always return a value(not null), going to the true case, and that's the reason to display green color. Try to look what your 'is_valid' function was returning.

Comment: We don't know what `is_valid` is, so we can't assume it'll "always return a value".

Comment: I said this based on the result of the photo he sent. In no case does the list contain blanks.

Comment: *shrug* Could be; there's nothing in a photo that indicates what's in the actual data, though.

Answer (score 0):

what the function getColor() is for ?

So if i understand you want to change the color of `<b>` element depending on `props.request.is_valid` ?

if that's correct you have to change style to :

`<b style={{ color : props.request.is_valid === null ? "green" : "red"></b>`

Comment: so is valid is returning a boolean

Comment: so you can just do `props.request.is_valid ? "green" : "red"`